# How can I clean cargo stuff?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I tried to install Parity (an Ethereum client) on my CHIP computer (similar to a Raspberry Pi with 4GB memory). I cloned the repository and ran

```
cargo build --release
```

After a while I noticed that  about 40% of the memory was used and I stopped the installation process. There was only 20% used before, so now I want to clean all of this Rust stuff. How can I do that?

Answer (score 26):

Cargo places all temporary build files into the `target/` directory. Sometimes, if not already present, Cargo also creates a `Cargo.lock` file. The directory can be removed by executing:

```
cargo clean
```

Cargo also saves the package index and the source code of dependencies globally in `~/.cargo/registry/`.

Comment: Well, the problem is that I've removed Parity folder with rm -rf :( So now, when I'm running cargo clean, there is an error "could not fnid 'Cargo.toml'"

Comment: @SergeyPotekhin If you've deleted the project directory, you've already done the equivalent of `cargo clean` and more. The global cache is probably your next place to look

Comment: Is it safe to do `rm -rf ~/.cargo/registry`?

Comment: @AaronMiller I'm actually not 100% sure. I think it's safe, but better ask a dedicated question!

Comment: @AaronMiller, [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51919907) suggests it's OK to do that.