# Cannot use cargo uninstall to uninstall packages in ~/.cargo: package id specification matched no package

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm having trouble uninstalling Cargo-installed packages from my system.

There are packages like rand-0.3.22 that are obviously installed under `$HOME/.cargo`

```
ls ~/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ra

racer-2.0.14/     rand-0.3.22/      rand-0.4.2/
rand-0.4.3/       rand-0.5.5/       rand_core-0.2.1/
rawpointer-0.1.0/ rayon-1.0.2/      rayon-core-1.4.1/
```

This can also be verified by using `cargo pkgid`

```
cargo pkgid -p rand

error: There are multiple `rand` packages in your project, and the specification `rand` is ambiguous.

Please re-run this command with `-p <spec>` where `<spec>` is one of the following:

rand:0.5.5
rand:0.4.3
rand:0.3.22
```

However, I'm unable to remove that package with `cargo uninstall`. None of these seem to work:

- `cargo uninstall rand`
- `cargo uninstall -- rand:0.4.3`
- `cargo uninstall https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index#rand:0.4.3`

For any of the commands above I get:

```
error: invalid package id specification: <name-of-package-i-specified>
```

This seems like a rather basic operation so I suspect it's something fundamental to how `cargo-uninstall` is to be used.

Any pointers?

Comment: `cargo uninstall` is for binaries (like `cargo-tree` for example) that you've installed, not dependencies of the project. If you want to remove one of your dependencies just edit `Cargo.toml` of the project.

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense. But how would I know in which one of my projects is that dependency in use? Notice that this may be a dependency of my dependency so it's not as straightforward as something like  `find Cargo.toml | xargs cat | grep <dep-name>`

Comment: You may take a look at [cargo-tree](https://github.com/sfackler/cargo-tree#cargo-tree)

Comment: or you can just check generated `Cargo.lock` - it lists all the recursive deps of the project

Comment: btw, what exactly are you trying to do? If I remember correctly, `~/.cargo/registry` is just a cache so you can delete anything you want from there - cargo will re-download what it needs later.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`cargo uninstall` undoes the effect of `cargo install`. You did not `cargo install` `rand`, because it is just a library, not an executable program. That means it was *not installed*.

The `~/.cargo/registry` is just a cache of build dependencies. Feel free to wipe it anytime; cargo will re-download and re-build whatever it needs when it does.

Yes, it is wrong. Cargo should be using `.local`, `.config` and `.cache` as appropriate; then it would be obvious what you can just clean up. Using arbitrary dot-dirs is an insult at this day and age. It was reported, several times probably. Nobody got around to fixing it yet.

Comment: *Using arbitrary dot-dirs is an insult at this day and age. It was reported, several times probably.* => I would note that this is *your* opinion, not an established fact. I can see both sides of the argument as "consistency across applications on the platform" vs "consistency of cargo across platforms".

Comment: so basically `cargo install` is not the same as `npm install` what I mean is it doesn't alter the Cargo.toml file and add the dependencies on its own.

Comment: @aRtoo, indeed, they are completely different things. Note that cargo does not need the equivalent of `npm install` without further parameters, because it can simply get the dependencies during `cargo build`. The [cargo-edit](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-edit) crate that adds commands to add and remove dependencies in `Cargo.toml`.

Comment: There is now also `cargo add`, which adds a dependency to `Cargo.toml`, just like `npm add`.

Comment: @MatthieuM. uh, no. For example I mount `~/.cache` as a `tmpfs` and I *don't* want it to survive reboots. Or maybe I want. I decide that on a machine-by-machine basis.